# Dependency on dependency leading to SNAPSHOT dependency in Maven

Tags: java, maven, apache-axis

I am trying to use Maven for a Java Application I am writing and am trying to use Java2WSDL with

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.axis2.maven2</groupId>
      <artifactId>axis2-java2wsdl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${java2wsdl.version}</version>
      <configuration>
        <className>com.barclays.hypercube.marketdata.Model.PointSeriesClient</className>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>java2wsdl</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

It seems that there is a dependency on

```
org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:jar:SNAPSHOT
```

Unsurprisingly this is not available from my Maven repository.

Is there any way to override this? Perhapos with a value in my settings.xml file.

Comment: Exclude it and specify with explicit version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude that unwanted jar from this maven. But first make sure you do not need this jar. Like [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
          <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```